# Marklogic search particular word in simple array values

Tags: arrays, search, marklogic-9

I have simple array in docs

```
Doc1- Arr=["Development,1","Test,2","Production,3","Production-Service,4"]
Doc2- Arr=["Development,1","Test,2","Production-Service,4"]
```

Here if I search for Production I should only get Doc1.
I am unable to use json property value query as I wont be getting associated number while querying.
I tried using word query but it's returning both docs.
can I get desire result using simple query?
Thanks for help in advance!!

Comment: It would appear that you are storing both a text value and some sort of index or ID for each of those array values. It might simplify things if you chose one or the other, or stored those values as some data structure, instead of a comma separated string value.

Answer (score 1):

Include the `,` in the word query, searching for `Production,` with a `punctuation-sensitive` search that should exclude the values that have `Production-Service`:

```
cts:search(doc(), 
  cts:json-property-word-query("Arr", "Production,")
)
```

And you could use a wildcarded expression:

```
cts:search(doc(), 
  cts:json-property-word-query("Arr", "Production,*", "wildcarded")
)
```

If the numeric suffix is always one digit, then could use `?` instead of `*`:

```
cts:search(doc(), 
  cts:json-property-word-query("Arr", "Production,?", "wildcarded")
)
```

Comment: I have docs similar to below samples too

Doc3- Arr=["Development,1","Test,2","Production,3","Sub-Production-Service,5"]
Doc4- Arr=["Development,1","Test,2","Sub-Production-Service,6"]

so,I tried wildcard unfiltered search with json property value but in that I am getting false positive results too.
I tried range query too
cts.andQuery([cts.elementRangeQuery('Arr','>=',"production,"),cts.elementRangeQuery('Arr','<',"production-")])
I created range index with collation builder http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S4 as to make it punctuation sensitive. But still no luck.

Comment: Tried filtered search with wildcard query. cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("Arr","production,*",["wildcarded","punctuation-sensitive", "case-insensitive", "whitespace-sensitive"])   
 Working as expected. but bit slower. Thanks